# Cocoa-Touch: UIPickerView viewForRow crashing

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.1

I have a UIPickerView, in it's delegate I'm trying to customize the view for a row. I'm using the 3.1 SDK.

So in the delegate I have:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
//    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return view;
}
```

From the apple docs:
If the previously used view (the view parameter) is adequate, return that. If you return a different view, the previously used view is released. The picker view centers the returned view in the rectangle for row.

When I run this, my UIPickerView control doesn't have any items in it, and after a short while crashes.
When I remove this particular method (which is optional for the delegate), I can see the labels I set via the titleForRow method, and it will no longer crash.

I'm pretty new to cocoa (and cocoa-touch), I'm not sure the view.backgroundColor thing will work, but even when returning the unmodified old view (which I must do anyway for most rows) crashes my app.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you implement *either* `–pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` or `–pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:`, but not both. What is happening is that it is not calling your `–pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` because it is using your `–pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:`. You are returning the `reusingView:` parameter, but that is `nil` the first time, because there was no "previously used view" for that row.

Comment: thanks, I'll have to try setting a view, I just assumed that the reusingView parameter would be the default view.

I'll try it in ~10 hrs